# Active Directory : how to retrieve username and password from Login control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, active-directory, asp.net-membership

I am using VS2005 C#.

I have a `Login` control on my web form and I am able to log in with correct credentials:

I have no backend code which supports my `Login` control.

I am using Active Directory Authentication, and below is a code snippet of my AD in `web.config`:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">       
    <providers>
        <clear/>
            <add name="MyADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
            System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
            applicationName="SOD" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
            connectionUsername="BTDP\Jimmy" connectionPassword="p@ssww0rd"
            attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" enableSearchMethods="true" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

I have declared a valid AD account above.

However, when a user of different credentials as the above logs in, the variable `User.Identity.Name` is identified as `BTDP\Jimmy` instead of the username of the logged in user, although the username and password the user entered went through AD authentication.

May I know if I am wrong for hard coding the credentials in the connection string?

How should I do it so that I am able to pump in the username and password into the connection string from the `Login` control in the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is something to do with either user impersonation or the fact that your application is querying the Domain Controller but impersonating as that user.
The [blog here](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/05/18/forms-authentication-with-active-directory-in-asp.net-2.0.aspx) might be helpful, has working example source you can try.

Comment: by any chance do you have any guides on managing users? i wish to display the functionality of managing users in ASP.NET tool via my web page, e.g. editing user roles

Comment: No problem, I have no guides on managing users sadly. Presumably you can query the AD for the users and save them to the database and manage settings from within your web app ? Or have a scheduled task to sync the users in the AD with your database?